# Any pattern for merging fields of multiple objects of same type

Tags: apex, class, object, merge, reference

I have a class called Texttypes and TextRoller as shown below:

```
public class TextTypes {
    List<String> goodTexts = new List<String>();
    List<String> badTexts = new List<String>();
    List<String> okTexts = new List<String>();
    List<String> aggresiveTexts = new List<String>();

    // other method definitions
}
```

Class TextRoller

```
public class TextRoller {

    public TextTypes rollTextType(){
        TextTypes initialTextType = new TextTypes();
        getTextTypeFromWeb(); // Returns textType
        getTextTypeFromPaper(); //Returns TextTypes
        getTextTypeFromFeedback();//Returns TextTypes

        //.. A few other methods that returns different texttypes

        //I want to merge the text types returned by all method in initialTextType reference.


    }

}
```

Inside the rollTextType() method,

I am trying to merge different textTypes that will be returned from **getTextTypeFromWeb**(), **getTextTypeFromPaper**() e.t.c. methods.

Currently, The way I am solving makes this process very lengthy but I think it will be faster as I am just dumping different kind of texts directly

```
TextTypes webTextType = getTextTypeFromWeb();
initialTextType.goodTexts.addAll(webTextType.goodTexts);
initialTextType.badTexts.addAll(webTextType.badTexts);
initialTextType.okTexts.addAll(webTextType.goodTexts);
initialTextType.aggresiveTexts.addAll(webTextType.aggresiveTexts);

TextTypes paperTextType = getTextTypeFromPaper();
initialTextType.goodTexts.addAll(paperTextType.goodTexts);
initialTextType.badTexts.addAll(paperTextType.badTexts);
initialTextType.okTexts.addAll(paperTextType.goodTexts);
initialTextType.aggresiveTexts.addAll(paperTextType.aggresiveTexts);

//Continue with other kinds of texttypes and assign to initialTextType
```

The other way I can solve it is by adding a method in TextTypes class:

```
public static TextTypes mergeTextTypes(TextTypes initialTextType, TextTypes mergeWithTextTypes) {
    initialTextType.goodTexts.addAll(mergeWithTextTypes.goodTexts);
    initialTextType.badTexts.addAll(mergeWithTextTypes.badTexts);
    initialTextType.okTexts.addAll(mergeWithTextTypes.goodTexts);
    initialTextType.aggresiveTexts.addAll(mergeWithTextTypes.aggresiveTexts);
    return initialTextType;
}
```

I then call above method [mergeTextTypes] method from  rollTextType() method inside TextRoller class.

```
initialTextType = TextTypes.mergeTextTypes(initialTextType, getTextTypeFromWeb());
initialTextType = TextTypes.mergeTextTypes(initialTextType, getTextTypeFromPaper());
initialTextType = TextTypes.mergeTextTypes(initialTextType, getTextTypeFromFeedback());
initialTextType = TextTypes.mergeTextTypes(initialTextType, getTextTypeFromPaperOtherWays());
```

Here, initialTextType is overridden many times and as a result, the above assignment process might become slow as there are lots and lots of messages in each list.

Can anyone help me in finding out a better way by which I can merge properties of different instances of the same type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the method static. Since you're modifying an instance, you'll get more legibility from an instance method.

```
public TextTypes mergeTextType(TextTypes mergeWithTextType) {
  this.goodTexts.addAll(mergeWithTextType.goodTexts);
  // ...
  return this;
}
```

Which allows you to write something like this

```
initialTextType.mergeTextType(getTextTypeFromWeb())
    .mergeTextType(getTextTypeFromPaper())
    .mergeTextType(getTextTypeFromFeedback());
```

This isn't a typo; the initialTextType returns itself, allowing you to call the same method with different parameters over and over again. This is a pattern known as method chaining. It makes the code a lot more compact without seriously affecting legibility.

Note: when you pass an Object (not a primitive, but all non-primitive types), any changes you make to the object will be reflected. If you did want to keep a static method, the following logic is equivalent to yours:

```
TextTypes.mergeTextTypes(initialTextType, getTextTypeFromWeb());
TextTypes.mergeTextTypes(initialTextType, getTextTypeFromPaper());
TextTypes.mergeTextTypes(initialTextType, getTextTypeFromFeedback());
TextTypes.mergeTextTypes(initialTextType, getTextTypeFromPaperOtherWays());
```

Because you're using "addAll" internally, you really are merging the values with the original initialTextType. In developer terms, this is an out parameter, since the results applied to initialTextType will be visible to the code that calls the method.

Comment: It might make more sense for `merge` to return a new instance, rather than modifying in place.

Comment: @AdrianLarson That's more of a philosophical point than anything. I do agree that "merge" suggests a new object should be returned. If I were me, I'd call it "addValues" or something so it's clear we're modifying the existing value. Since Apex doesn't have custom "immutable" types, and given the apparent use of the object, I don't think it matters which approach is used, so long as it is consistent.